# Unable to publish an atom plugin

Tags: atom-editor

I am facing few issues. So whenever I am trying to publish a atom plugin using `apm publish` I am facing this error

```
Package must be in a Git repository before publishing: https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo
```

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/90365542/154661659-c3866f5c-e4df-46bc-9b91-e0e444bad172.png

Apparently the package is in a github repository which is public as well https://github.com/avneesh0612/react-nextjs-snippets/tree/main/packages/atom

Answer (score 0):

The package must reside in the *root directory* of a GitHub repository.
In your case the package is in `https://github.com/avneesh0612/react-nextjs-snippets/tree/main/packages/atom` but it must be directly in `https://github.com/avneesh0612/react-nextjs-snippets/`.
That is, there must be a `package.json` and a .git directory in that folder.